# Calculating the probability distribution function of a realization of a random process

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I have a realization of a continuous random process, $y = f(t)$, a function of time ($t$). I am trying to calculate $P(y = Y_0)$, the probability distribution function of $f(t)$. Am I right in saying that the Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) of $f(t)$, i.e. $P(f(t) > Y_0)$ can be represented as:

\begin{align} P(f(x) > Y_0)\quad  = \quad C(Y_0) \quad=\quad  \lim_{L \to \infty}\frac{1}{2L}\int^{L}_{-L}{\frac{1 + sgn\left({f(t) - Y_0} \right)}{2} dt}\end{align}

\begin{align} \text{Where, }\text{ }sgn(n) = \begin{cases} 1,  & \text{if $n > 0$ } \\
0, & \text{if $n \le 0$} \end{cases} \end{align}

**Reasoning:** 
when $f(x) > Y_0$, the integrand amounts to $1$ and is $0$ otherwise. Thus the integral simply results in the length of the region where $f(x)$ is greater than $Y_0$. Division by $2L$ is the normalization factor for the CDF.

In case this happens to be correct, how would I proceed to differentiate this expression in order to obtain the required PDF of the process? Is this a reasonable direction to proceed along in order to calculate the PDF?

I am a beginner to the subject so I apologize for any conceptual errors in the question. Would be glad to clarify any other inconsistencies.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have one realized path of the process and want to estimate its density? It's unclear what you mean by "calculate". If you mean estimate, It's impossible unless you assume it has iid and stationary increments, like a brownian motion.

Comment: Yes, I have one realized path of a process, the density of which I wish to **estimate**. The process can be assumed to be Brownian, i.e. is has stationary increments and is i.i.d